# using text box and label inheritance

Tags: wpf, xaml

IM using lot of text boxes and label that have lot of common beside ,my question is if 
in wpf instead of copy paste ?

for example if I have the following text box and instead the name and the place on the screen 
I want that all text box have the same behaviors

```
<TextBox x:Name="name2"  
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    AllowDrop="True" 
                    PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
                    PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
                    PreviewDragOver="DropText_PreviewDragOver"

                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Grid.Column="4" Margin="4,50,0,0" Grid.Row="2"
                  />

        <TextBox x:Name="name1"  
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    AllowDrop="True" 
                    PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
                    PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
                    PreviewDragOver="DropText_PreviewDragOver"

                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Height="20" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"  Grid.Column="4" Margin="4,75,0,0" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

Comment: Use Styles for that. See e.g. [A Guided Tour of WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18388/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-5-Styles) or [Using styles in WPF video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBs5eEsIk3A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Style`, which will store all the settings for the control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" /> 
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,75,0,0" />
</Style>
```

If style define the key, it will only apply to the control that it explicitly indicate. Example:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxOneStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="False" /> 
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TextBoxTwoStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" /> 
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,75,0,0" />
</Style>
```

Using:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxOne"
         Style="{StaticResource TextBoxOneStyle}" />

<TextBox Name="TextBoxTwo"
         Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTwoStyle}" />
```

You can also specify the event handler via [`EventSetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewDragEnter" Handler="DropText_PreviewDragEnter" />
</Style>
```

Please see this link, for more information:

[Styling and Templating MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)